# Why fontSize? Why would font-size not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

While I was changing heading font size on DevTool, I noticed that I couldn't use

```
heading.style.font-size = '2em';
```

but instead I had to use

```
heading.style.fontSize = '2em';
```

Why is that?

Comment: You want to put in quotes. `heading.style.fontSize = "2em";`.

Comment: because `font-size` could be parsed as `font - size` - meaning it's taking a variable called `font`, and one called `size` - it doesn't work for js

Comment: maybe because `-` mean minus ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dashes cannot be used in dot notation because property names are identifiers. The `-` is a keyword for things such as subtraction.

You can however do the following.

```js
document.querySelector("div").style["font-size"] = "7em";
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```